# (Error) TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy haciendo un programa para un proyecto y necesito hacer un promedio entre un seno y un coseno:

```
def simul(pres, maxi, ctrl):
    prom = []
    segundos = range(ctrl, 1000+1)
    print("Resultado:")
    for s in segundos:
        print(f"{s} segundos")
        print(f"Presion: {pres} mmHg.\n")
        prom.append(pres)
        if pres < maxi:
            test1=np.sin(pres)
            test2=np.cos(pres)
            pres += 4
            prom = np.mean(test1, test2)
        else:
            test1 = np.sin(pres)
            test2 = np.cos(pres)
            pres -= 15
            prom = np.mean(test1, test2)
```

Es una función y utilizo estos datos de entrada:

```
simul(10, 90, 0)
```

Me sale este error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

No se que hacer ayuda.

Comment: El error se debe a que usas mal `numpy.mean`, debería ser en todo caso `prom = np.mean((test1, test2))`. No obstante, en `prom = np.mean()` haces que `prom` sea un escalar, pero la defines como una lista originalmente.... No se muy bien que quieres hacer con esto, en la siguiente iteración `prom.append` fallará...

Comment: @FJSevilla se supone que es una grafica y queria hacer un promedio entre la grafica del seno y del coseno pero es mi primer programa trabajando con python pero investigare mas para solucionar mi error gracias

Comment: ¿No deberías hacer `prom.append(np.mean((test1, test2)))` en vez de `prom.append(pres)`? El error que comentas originalemente se soluciona como comento, al hacer `np.mean(test1, test2)` realmente haces `np.mean(a=test1, axis=test2)`, esto provoca el fallo al pasar como eje un float y no un entero. Se soluciona metiendo ambos valores en un iterable , como una tupla `np.mean((test1, test2))` lo que equivale a `np.mean(a=(test1, test2))`  o un array NumPy.

Comment: @FJSevilla ya corregi el error segun tus consejos pero me sale un nuevo error:  AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Eso es lo que te comento, arriba. Al hacer `prom = np.mean()` la variable `prom` deja de ser una lista y pasa a ser un float... Si prom va a almacenar los promedios de cada iteración deberías hacer en principio lo que comento al inicio de mi comentario anterior

Comment: @FJSevilla ok, ya lo corregi pero aparece otro error (dios me estoy deprimiendo): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test1' referenced before assignment

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95890/discussion-between-erik-alcantara-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estás pasando de forma incorrecta tus valores a numpy.mean. La firma del método es:

```
numpy.mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>)
```

Donde `a` es el array o un objeto iterable que se pueda convertir en array. Este array contiene los valores cuya media queremos calcular. El segundo argumento es el eje (en caso de tenemos un array multidimensional) sobre el que queremos aplicar la operación (media por filas, por columnas, etc).

Cuando en tu código haces:

```
prom = np.mean(test1, test2)
```

realmente haces:

```
prom = np.mean(a=test1, axis=test2)
```

al intentar obtener los elementos pertenecientes al eje especificado, NumPy hace `a.shape[axis]`, como le has pasado como eje test2 que es un float tienes el error mostrado. Sea como sea, aún sin el error, esto calcularía la media de `test1` (un float), que es como cabe esperar `test1`...

La solución es simplemente pasar un array NumPy o otro contenedor (como una tupla) con ambos valores como primer argumento:

```
np.mean((test1, test2))
```

Por otro lado, a `prom` (que es una lista), le agregas como nuevo item el valor de `pres` en cada iteración, cuando deberías agregar en principio el valor del promedio. Es más, al hacer `prom = np.mean(test1, test2)` reasignas a la variable `prom` un escalar (la media), por lo que a partir de ese momento deja de apuntar a  una lista y en la siguiente iteración la llamada a `prom.append` terminará en un excepción.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def simul(pres, maxi, ctrl):
    promedios = []
    segundos = range(ctrl, 1000 + 1)
    print("Resultado:")

    for s in segundos:
        sinv = np.sin(pres * 2)
        cosv = np.cos(pres)
        promedio = np.mean((sinv, cosv))
        promedios.append(promedio)

        print(f"{s} segundos")
        print(f"Presion: {pres} mmHg.\n")
        print(f"Sin-Cos promedio: {promedio}")

        if pres < maxi:
            pres += 4
        else:
            pres -= 15

    plt.rcParams["toolbar"] = "None"
    plt.plot(segundos, promedios)
    plt.title("Aumento de PIC")
    plt.ylabel("PIC") 
    plt.show()

simul(10, 90, 0)
```